# myanmar font on firefox at ubuntu didn't work out

Tags: 12.04, firefox, fonts

I am a new user of ubuntu 12.04 from MYANMAR. I tried to install myanmar font to read the myanmar website but it didn't work out. Please Someone can help me out?

Comment: How did you try to install the font? Also, define "didn't work out".

Comment: i change keyboard layout to "buremse".

Comment: So, you did not install the myanmar font?

Answer (score 0):

Visit this [link](http://www.myordbok.com/myanmar-fonts/) to download anyone of the fonts mentioned below

- Myanmar 1,2,3
- Paduak
- Parabaik
- Zawgyi-One

download the **.ttf** font and place the font in /home/user/.fonts(`~/.fonts`) directory. If the .fonts directory is not available, go ahead and create.

Refresh the fonts cache using command.

`sudo fc-cache -f -v`

This should help you to read the Myanmar font properly

Comment: Thank that help me a lot. But sometime why browser need to force quite ?? When i enter into myanmar site (like planet.com.mm), page only show half and browser didn't work out anymore and i force quite it.

Comment: Does it happen only when you open Myanmar site or for all other sites?